# Mercado Pago, back_urls formato

Tags: php, mercadopago, mercadolibre

Que tal!, gracias por su tiempo, resulta que estoy intentando integrar un carrito de compras muy basico con MercadoPago. Pero Recibo el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MercadoPagoException' with message 'back_urls invalid. Wrong format'
```

Estoy usando la libreria para PHP con el siguiente codigo

```
$mp = new MP('xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxx'); 
            $mp->sandbox_mode(true);


            $preference_data = array(
                "items" => array(
                    array(
                        "title" => "Multicolor kite",
                        "description" => "Multicolor kite - prueba",
                        "quantity" => 1,
                        "currency_id" => "ARS", 
                        "unit_price" => 1.00
                    )
                ),
                "payer" => array(
                    array(
                        "name" => "Pepe Argento",
                        "email" => "pepe.argento@otecno.com"
                    )
                ),
                "external_reference" => "230688",
                "auto_return" => "approved",
                "back_urls" => array(
                    array(
                        "success" => "http://cualquierpagina.com"
                    )
                )
            );

            $preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);

            echo $preference['response']['sandbox_init_point'];
```

despues tomo el string que devuelve en $preference['response']['sandbox_init_point']; y lo pongo en un botón.

Si remuevo el back_url y el auto_return, lo envía perfecto, toma los datos y parece funcionar todo bien. Pero si no me manda el error antes mencionado, a mi entender debe ser algo de formato, pero no importa como la ponga la pagina, sigue rebotandolo.

Que es lo que esta mal? Alguien podría darme una mano con el tema?

En algún lado leí que el sandbox no funcionaba, y que había que hacer todo en modo real con usuarios de prueba, la verdad es que leí la documentación de como hacer un usuario de prueba y no comprendí en donde o como.

Por su tiempo y atención muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te está sobrando un array, en lugar de esto:

```
"back_urls" => array(
    array(
        "success" => "http://cualquierpagina.com"
    )
)
```

Debería ser:

```
"back_urls" => array(
    "success" => "http://cualquierpagina.com"
)
```

Es cierto que ya no funciona el sandbox y ahora hay que manejar usuarios de prueba. Te paso el código para crearlos, para que no sufras lo que sufrí yo xD:

```
    $mp = new MP($client_id, $client_secret);
    $access_token = $mp->get_access_token();

    // Argentina: id "MLA".
    $data = array('site_id' => 'MLA');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/test_user?access_token=$access_token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

    // Respuesta en formato json
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $user = json_decode($response, true);
```

Vas a tener que crear dos y usar uno como comprador y otro como vendedor.
Luego iniciar sesión en MercadoPago con el email y el password del usuario vendedor y obtener los valores client_id y client_secret para poder conectar a la api y ejecutar las transacciones.

En la respuesta, los datos del usuario te va a aparecer algo como:

```
array(
    'id'          => '123456789',
    'nickname'    => 'XXXXXXXXX',
    'password'    => 'XXXXXXXXX',
    'site_status' => 'active',
    'email'       => 'XXXXXXXXX'
)
```

Hace varios meses que usé este código y supongo que todavía servirá, aunque con MercadoPago nunca se sabe... ^_^

Comment: Funciona perfecto!, sin embargo, sacando el array sobrante veo que anda bien, por lo menos pongo la tarjeta de credito de prueba y pasa y ya me devuelve a la pagia con datos via GET, que tendre que analizar. Pero, creacion de usuarios OK, y lo del array con sandbox OK. Genio!

Comment: jajaj mejor asi, me alegro que te haya servido!